# Automating GUI operations of Windows applications that are not web-based

Tags: windows, gui, automation, powershell

Is there an open source application that automates GUI operations?  I'd like to automate GUI applications that are not web-based.  I want the application to possibly recognize screenshots and locations.  But I'd settle for an application that issues tab and enter key in succession.  I want an application to automate operations of diverse Windows applications including RDP sessions to other servers.

Answer (score 1):

[SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/) has a motto of "Automate Anything You See" - it is a Java based testing framework that uses Image Processing to search the screen for specific elements and perform actions on them driven by [python](http://www.python.org)/ruby/JavaScript scripting.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Linux, OS-X & Windows
- Comes with its own IDE
- Works even with problems like windows, buttons, etc, not being in a consistent position - as long as they look the same they can be identified.
- Does **not** need to know resource IDs, etc.
- Can issue:

  - Click
  - Double Click
  - Delays
  - Type keyboard input, etc.
- conditional actions e.g. if this icon is found click it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are dozens, here are a few:

- AutoIt & AutoHotKey are the grandparents of the type
- If Python is your poison, how about [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/)
- There are many more, starting with those, you will surely find the others
- [This list](http://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/) may give you more clues